# Add custom link to specific WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress

1 have 3 WordPress menu. i want to add custom link to menu 2.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom_link', 10, 2);
function add_custom_link($items, $args) {
            $items .= '<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>';
    return $items;
}
```

i tried the above code but it is adding link to add created menu.
i am doing this in plugin.

Comment: add the custom links in wordpress backend Menu

Comment: There is option in the backend to add custom links.

Comment: i am doing this in plugin.